# How to help GHC infer that `Arrows (Domains func) (CoDomain func) ~ func`

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, injective-function

Consider the `Arrows`, `Domains` and `CoDomain` type-families defined [in the `agda` codebase](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Utils/TypeLevel.hs#L72-L93).

Obvious to the programmer, it holds that `Arrows (Domains func) (CoDomain func) ~ func`. But I can't get `curries (Proxy :: Proxy (Domains func)) (Proxy :: Proxy (CoDomain func)) undefined :: func` through GHC's type-checker. That's because GHC isn't smart enough to infer that the combination of `Domains` and `CoDomain` is injective. Is there a way to teach GHC nonetheless? I'd imagine some case split over the `IsBase` predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be better for you to change `Currying` to be indexed by `func`?

```
class Currying func where
  curries :: (Products (Domains func) -> CoDomain func) -> func
  uncurries :: func -> Products (Domains func) -> CoDomain func

instance Currying b => Currying (a -> b) where
  curries f a = curries (f . (,) a)
  uncurries f (a, as) = uncurries (f a) as

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (IsBase b ~ 'True) => Currying b where
  curries f = f ()
  uncurries b _ = b
```

---

We can also assert axioms in this way, though I'm not even sure this one is safe:

```
arrowAxiom :: forall func. func :~: Arrows (Domains func) (CoDomain func)
arrowAxiom = unsafeCoerce Refl
```

The equality can be put in scope by pattern matching on the axiom.

Comment: How would I match on the structure of `func` that way?

Comment: I added instances to my answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Actually, there's [one more case](https://github.com/sgraf812/datafix/blob/66a5236791c81249c0e5dd8c682d9a3013d2163b/src/Datafix/Utils/TypeLevel.hs#L136) I'd like to optimize for. Is that still possible that way? I imagine that leads to three tiers of overlaps.

Anyway, the axiom approach works just fine, too.

Comment: Hmm.. come to think of it, I'm not sure if can really use `Currying func` in my code, because I do stuff like [this](https://github.com/sgraf812/datafix/blob/66a5236791c81249c0e5dd8c682d9a3013d2163b/src/Datafix/Description.hs#L83), where I return non-`Base` types and the selected `Currying` would not [do the right thing here](https://github.com/sgraf812/datafix/blob/66a5236791c81249c0e5dd8c682d9a3013d2163b/src/Datafix/Description.hs#L234)

Comment: For the three-case situation, you can define three instances `(IsBase b ~ 'True) => Currying b`, `(IsBase b ~ 'True) => Currying (a -> b)`, `Currying (a2 -> b) => Currying (a1 -> a2 -> b)`.

Comment: Exactly, but I'm not sure which instance should overlap which.

Comment: The first two should be `OVERLAPPABLE`. [This chapter of the GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-overlap) explains how these pragmas affect the selection algorithm. There are different combinations that also work, but  `OVERLAPPABLE` is almost always sufficient in my experience.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: As for the more general problem, I don't see a good way to extend my approach (having considered 1) indexing `Currying` by the number of arguments to take, 2) matching on the desired result type). I guess it depends on what information is more readily available. The simplest solution with the original class may be to just let the type equality float into the toplevel constraints.